# How to fill in the names of the students in one column based on their register number in other column in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to fill the names of the students in a particular column based on the register number in the previous column in excel. For example, in column A1 the register number is 1. Now in column B1 i want to fill the name of the student whose roll number is 1.

Comment: Does your file contain multiple students with roll number equals 1? Because if not, you can simply vlookup that right?

Answer (score 0):

If your student data is in columns C (number) and D (name), use

```
=vlookup(A1,C:D,2,FALSE)
```